# How to clear the BIOS security password on this notebook?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, bios, passwords

I recently got an Acer Aspire E11 (E3-112m) and in order to install another OS I had to set a Supervisor password, so I used a well known password to me, the problem is that such password contains a special character *!* which the password prompt won't let me input, though it let me when I had to set the password (buggy prompt I believe). Now everytime I need to change something in the BIOS I have to fail 3 times and go to [bios-pw.org](http://bios-pw.org) to generate a master key.

I have already tried several different methods to clear it:

- Removing the CMOS battery
- Looking for the reset jumper (which doesn't even exist).

I also noticed there were 2 weird buttons on the front and back sides of the motherboard, I don't know what they are for but I also pressed them (while both the CMOS and the regular battery were disconnected). All of this without luck, the password just won't reset (though the RTC did).

Are there other ways to reset the Supervisor/Admin password on this model?

Comment: Won't it allow you to set/change the password once you're in the BIOS? At that point you should be in the same "buggy" prompt location that originally let you set a bad one even if it requires that you enter the old password.

Comment: That is the problem, I am prompted with the old password but everything I input is wrong. I am pretty sure the password I'm using is correct since I wrote it down at the time I set it.

Comment: You're prompted for this within the BIOS settings, and are you able to try many combinations without then being locked out? If so, try variations of capitalization, as well as things like an extra space or tab at the end - you may have gotten a "stray" character on there.

Comment: You will have to ask Acer...

Comment: Well, I only have three attempts before it locks itself and I have to do a hard power off and that'd be my last resort

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the password generated by bios-pw.org and presss enter instantly keep pressing del or f2 to enter bios screen and then disable boot password and exit and save.

Comment: I don't think this would work because the password change prompt doesn't take in the "backup" passwords, and it doesn't display a code to generate the alt password